# Pandas merge columns with different names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge a spreadsheet using the merge function with pandas. I'm trying to combine the columns ID & id together, TrackName & name, ArtistName & artists, Danceability & danceability, etc. from the 2018 and 2019 spreadsheets.

Here is the code that I tried to use when merging,

```
pd.merge(df, df2, left_on=  ['TrackName', 'ArtistName','ID'],
            right_on= ['name', 'artists','id'])
```

however, I'm always getting an error saying that I can't merge on int64 and object columns. I'm not sure how to use concat to merge these columns together, so could someone help me out?

Also, even when I use merge to only merge the object columns and not the ID, (like this)

```
pd.merge(df, df2, left_on=  ['TrackName', 'ArtistName'],
            right_on= ['name', 'artists'])
```

it still doesn't work and the columns don't merge properly. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I'd really appreciate some help if possible!

Here are the spreadsheets: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AXQUjG2IfAoiai_N60APXPH_bzlqLa7CzNnTV0zB5eg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: the columns between 2018 and 2019 seem to be quite different, so not sure what you want can be achieved without some data cleaning anyway.

However, for your specific error - that is because the ID column in 2018 is `int64` i.e. numbers, and the id column in 2019 is `object` i.e. strings and pandas does not know how to equate the two. i.e. how to equate id = 1 with id = asjhiuaf32das?

Comment: @compilation-error I'm trying to combine all the columns so that it's just one big spreadsheet and all the similar columns are grouped together. The other columns (i.e. instrumentalness which only shows up in 2018) can just be columns where for 2019 it just has NaN values.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.merge()` is a class function orientated to produce joins of Databases with *primary keys* and *foreign keys* as in SQL Style databases. See [Difference Between Primary and Foreign Key](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-primary-key-and-foreign-key/).

The problem here is that you are trying to introduce values of different dtypes (use `df.dtypes` to see the types of all columns in your DataFrames) to an existing column. That happens because pandas takes the left `DataFrame` assigned in the function as the "base", and tries to add new records to it, since the dtype is different, it causes an error.

In fact, the documentation is more likely to appear as a `pd.DataFrame` method, because it is behaved as a (say) "Mother DataFrame that receives new rows". See documentation [pd.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

The error also recommends to use the `pandas.concat` method, since it sees that the `dtypes` are different and thinks you may are willing to just join two `DataFrames`. Which can be preferible, if there are no existing records that have the same *TrackName* and *Artist* (for example), in that case you would like to join them with a concat, because there is no additional information you can gain about a record using another `DataFrame`.

My recommendation is: rename columns in `DataFrame 2019` as they are in `DataFrame 2018`, with the same name if they refer to the same attribute, you can use `pd.DataFrame.rename`, then, change the `dtype` of the columns that you will like to do the merge on and make sure they are the same. Finally, try to do an *Outer Join* with the `merge` function, using the Song Name, for example. You will see if there are matches or see that all records may be different databases.

Answer (score 0):

So you are not able to merge on ID as ID is of object datatype in one table and int in other table:

```
df_2018.dtypes

id                   object
name                 object
artists              object

df_2019.dtypes

ID                 int64
TrackName         object
ArtistName        object
```

Now I tried merging two tables on 'name' and 'artists' and I was able to do that. Here is the code:

```
new_df = pd.merge(df_2018, df_2019, left_on=['name','artists'], right_on = ['TrackName','ArtistName'])

new_df.columns

Index(['id', 'name', 'artists', 'danceability', 'energy', 'key', 'loudness',
       'mode', 'speechiness', 'acousticness', 'instrumentalness', 'liveness',
       'valence', 'tempo', 'duration_ms', 'time_signature', 'ID', 'TrackName',
       'ArtistName', 'Genre', 'BeatsPerMinute', 'Energy', 'Danceability',
       'LoudnessdB', 'Liveness', 'Valence', 'Length', 'Acousticness',
       'Speechiness', 'Popularity'],
      dtype='object')
```

I could get all the columns as desired. Let me know if you are still facing any issues. Do share columns for which you are facing an issue